# Transformation R data frame - applying running median

Tags: r, dataframe

I need help transforming following **data frame in R**:

```
-----------------------------------
| ID   | x_1  | x_2  | ... | x_m  | 
|---------------------------------|
| id_1 | x_11 | x_12 | ... | x_1m |
|---------------------------------|
|              ...                |
|---------------------------------|
| id_n | x_n1 | x_n2 | ... | x_nm |
-----------------------------------
```

I have one id column and m measurements **(x_1 - x_m)** obtained from n experiments. For each experiment/row, I would like to smooth the m measurement values using a **running median**.

Is there an easy way to do such a transformation in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(zoo)
apply( dfrm[-1], 1, rollmedian, k=5)
```

OR:

```
cbind(dfrm[1], as.dataframe( apply( dfrm[-1], 1, rollmedian, k=5) ) )
```

Comment: This solution works. However it does not preserve the data frame. The output is a matrix. I'm looking for a solution that only updates the values without changing the data frame.

Comment: "Preserve the dataframe"? you nmay be working with a computing model that is not a good fit for learning R. As a general rule R does not modify objects in place. You could always assign the output of a function to an existing name. I find that somewhat dangerous and prefer to give new objects their own names.

Comment: Sorry if my answer was confusing. I was looking for the second solution you posted. Thanks!

However the matrix you get from the apply function has to be transposed.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @DWin's answer but using *stats* `?runmed`:

```
apply(dfrm[-1], 1, runmed, k=5)
```